# Python text fight: printing on one line

Tags: python

I am having a problem on line 37 where I try to type a bunch of print statements on one line. One to tell you something, one with a choice statement and another with the variable `enemy11`. How could I print all that on one line?

Also, with the random choice, say it chooses to punch, how can I detect that so I can take it away from your health? So it chooses punch. It recognizes it punched and takes away punch from your HP.

```
hp=100
enemy1=100
enemy2=200
boss=500
punch=10
kick=20
fatality=99999999

attacks = ['kick', 'punch', 'fatality']
from random import choice


from time import sleep

print("Welcome to Ultimate Fight Club Plus")
sleep(1)
print("What is your name?")
name=raw_input("> ")
print("Good luck"), name
sleep(1)
print("Choose your opponent")
enemy11=raw_input("> ")
print("You chose"), enemy11
sleep(1)
print("his health is"), enemy1
sleep(1)
print("Fight!")
while enemy1>1:
        print("You can kick or punch")
        fight1=raw_input("> ")
        if fight1=="punch":
                enemy1 -= punch
                print("You punch him in the face")
                sleep(1)
                print("His health is now"), enemy1
                sleep(1)
                print(enemy11) print choice(attacks) print("You")
        if fight1=="kick":
                enemy1 -= kick
                print("You kick him.")
                sleep(1)
                print("His health is now"), enemy1
print("You win!")
```

Comment: This is a pretty cool program !

Comment: And I am having a lot of fun programming it!

Answer (score 2):

I am new to Python too. Try this:

```
print(enemy11, choice(attacks), "You")
```

Comment: I must be supernoob then, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So this is your line -

```
print(enemy11) print choice(attacks) print("You")
```

You can get the "choice(attack)"  variable in some temp variable and then print..

```
temp = choice(attack)
print ("%s %s You" % (enemy11, temp))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, I usually go for string formatting, as you can specify meaningful names for your parameters:

```
print "{who} {action} you".format(who=enemy11, action=choice(attacks))
```

You should check out the [tutorial on python2.7](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html)
or [python3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for advanced formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

Separate items with a comma to combine them on one line.

```
print(enemy11,choice(attacks),"You")
```

Also see the documentation for `print` and `format`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use formatted strings like so

```
 print('%s %s You' % (enemy11, choice(attacks)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the list off attacks to a dictionary associating them with their damage:

```
attacks = {'punch':10, 'kick':20, 'fatality':99999999}
```

Then use the result of `choice()` to lookup the amount of damage to do.

```
thisAttack = choice(attacks.keys())
hp -= attacks[thisAttack]
print("%s's %s leaves you with %s hp."% (enemy11, thisAttack, hp))
```

You can use the user's input in `fight1` to lookup their damage as well, but will need to handle when they don't choose a valid option:

```
try:
    thisAttack = attacks[fight1]
except KeyError as e:
    print "You're not that flexible."
    continue #restart the While loop
```

Comment: Where do the keys and keys come in?

Comment: I've only seen the key thing in java

Comment: `choice()` expects a simple list. `dict.keys()` returns a list of all its keys. We use the one `choice()` selects to lookup the corresponding value: `value = dict[key]`


http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write(enemy11)
sys.stdout.write(attacks)
sys.stdout.write("you")

stdout.write prints the matter in same line so for adding spaces in between 
you have to add it seperately...

sys.stdout.write(enemy11)
sys.stdout.write(" ")
sys.stdout.write(choice(attacks))
sys.stdout.write(" ")
sys.stdout.write("you")
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
print ("%s %s %s" % (enemy11, choice(attacks), "You"))
```

Comment: print("%s %s You" % (enemy11, choice(attacks))) this is the right way